# typoscript two depending menus

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I'd like to have a horizontal menu at the top of the website and a vertical menu with the menu levels 2 and 3 at the left side of the website.

Unfortunately my typoscript shows the same menu for both areas.

Any ideas what's wrong?

```
# Hauptmenu
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu.special = directory
lib.mainMenu.special.value = 1
lib.mainMenu.entryLevel = 0
lib.mainMenu.1 = TMENU
lib.mainMenu.1.NO {
  wrapItemAndSub = <div class="grid_1_menu"> | </div > |*| <div class="grid_1_menu"> | </div > |*| <div class="grid_1_menu grid_1_menu_end"> | </div >
}

# Seitennavigation
lib.subMenu= HMENU
lib.subMenu.special = directory
lib.subMenu.special.value = 1
lib.subMenu.entryLevel = 1
lib.subMenu.wrap = <ul class="sub-menu" id="menu-level-1">|</ul>
lib.subMenu.1 = TMENU
lib.subMenu.1.NO {
  wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first"> | </li> |*| <li class="middle"> | </li> |*| <li class="last""> | </li>
}

lib.subMenu.2 < lib.subMenu.1
lib.subMenu.2.wrap = <ul class="sub-menu" id="menu-level-2">|</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy:

```
special = directory
special.value = 123
```

creates a menu from `ALL` items inserted in `page` or `sysfolder` with uid = 123 , by writing the value (`1` in your case) you instruct the TS to build menu from pages under (probably) main page.

As you can see in this sample, `special` directive takes precedens over the `entryLevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough I don't understand exactly why, I had to remove

```
lib.subMenu.special.value = 1
```